# ASP.NET MVC I'm trying to add a review product (http post) in the same page using (partial view)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

`_getProductReviews.cshtml`:

I'm calling my partial view like this:

```
<p>@Html.Partial("_CreateR");</p>
```

`_CreateR.cshtml`:

This code is auto generated by the controller:

```
@model Commerce.Domain.Entites.t_review

@using (Html.BeginForm())

{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">

    <h4>t_review</h4>

    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.text, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.text)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.text)

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.customer_id, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.customer_id)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.customer_id)

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.product_fk, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.product_fk)

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.product_fk)

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">

            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

          </div>

      </div>

   </div>

}
```

`ProductController`:

```
// GET: /Product/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
     return View();
}

//
// POST: /Product/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,text,title,customer_id,product_fk")] t_review review)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            prose.CreateReview(review);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(review);
}
```

When I use a simple view with actionlink it works but when I try to use partial View shows this msg

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Commerce.Domain.Entites.t_review]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Commerce.Domain.Entites.t_review'.

Comment: The message should be obvious - The model for `_getProductReviews.cshtml` is `List<t_review>` and you then pass that to `_CreateR.cshtml` whose model is `t_review` (not `List<t_review>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.Partial` renders a view **without** calling the `Controller` first.

`Html.Action` calls a `Controller` `Action` which can return like everything: a view, a partial view, json, etc.

As a general guideline, you should use `Html.Partial` only when you want to display static content or when you have access to the model required. For everything else, like wen you want to return more data from the server, use `Html.Action`.

Comment: can i use 'Html.Action' to call my view in the same page?

Comment: Well you cannot load a View inside another View, but you can use Html.Action to render a Partial View inside a View.

Comment: so how can i list my product reviews with a button in the bottom to add one, all in the same view?

Comment: Use one (or more) Partial Views in in your View.

Comment: i did that it work for listing reviews but i can't figure out how to add one with staying in the same view like comment in facebook .

Comment: There are multiple solutions for this depending how much you want to work on this. The best solution would be to have the add form in a partial view, submit it with ajax and once completed use JS to add the review to the listing. The easier solution would be to have both the listing and the add form in the same partial view and save and relist reviews on submit.